# Auto Resize of Label in PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have added a Label in PyQt4 which contains an image. This image fits the window completely when it is not maximised. My aim is that the label should auto resize and fit the window completely even when maximised. My code is as follows:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
       MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
       MainWindow.resize(1047, 600)
       self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
       self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
       self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1081, 551))
       self.label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
       self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("Capture.PNG")))
       self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
   if __name__ == "__main__":
      import sys
      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
      MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
      ui = Ui_MainWindow()
      ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
      MainWindow.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please tell me how shall I modify my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following:

- Set the `centralwidget` to be the `centralWidget` of the `QMainWindow`.
- Use layout to place the `QLabel` inside the `centralwidget`.
- Enable the `ScaledContents` property of `QLabel`.

---

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) # <--
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Capture.PNG"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True) # <--
        lay.addWidget(self.label) # <--
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have certain Push buttons present on the label, with reference to certain points on the label. Now, when the label gets expanded, these Push Buttons retained their initial coordinates and did not change with the label. Is it somehow possible for us to make sure that these push buttons also change in accordance to the change in label !?

Comment: @MehulBhatia How do you want your position to change? Create a new question by providing a [mcve] and I could help you.

Comment: Very surely sir @eyllansec. I will create a new question !!